# on print command by js reduce fontsize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

for print data i have js code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

But in case it generate the print option and save the file but because of scrool in datatbale its not printing complete data .. so i want to reduce the fontsize in time of print how can i solve that can anyone please help 
My anchor is given below:

```
<a href="" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')"> <i aria-hidden="true" style="color:black" class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
```

Comment: Use media queries in your CSS.

Comment: cant we do this from javascript ??  i added already <style type="text/css">
  @media print{
   body{
       font-size:9px;
       font-family:"Times New Roman";
   }
}
</style> but its not working dont know why

Answer (score 0):

A new css file with [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) will allow to set the style of the printing document.This file need to be include in root html, or use any existing css file to add @media print media query

```
@media print{
  // add font-size here

}
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">

@media print{
       font-size:9px;
       font-family:"Times New Roman";

}
</style>   added this but not working

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "small";
```

here 'MyP' Your Id

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "small";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="myP" style="font-size:30px;">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set font size</button>
 


</body>
</html>
```